# Проверка даты Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Как сделать, чтобы при запуске программы начинался отчет времени (15 дней), чтобы по истечении 15 дней программа удалила себя.

Желательно с **if else** сделать.

Comment: Еще добавь проверку "текущая дата должна быть больше даты предыдущего запуска"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так

```
    OnCreate;
    begin
    if DaysBetween(startdate,now)>15 then application.terminate; 
    end;
```

В переменной **startdate** держишь дату первого запуска, а где её держать это уже решай сам, хочешь в реестре хочешь в файле, если знаний хватает, то в самом екзешнике в ресурсах можешь держать.

не забудь в **Uses** добавить **DateUtils**

Comment: Я как месяц делфи изучаю,ошибку в startdate.
Что сделать переменную? И как это сделать.)

Comment: Для начала проверяешь есть ли у тебя переменная, или это первый запуск, если запуск первый то сохраняешь переменную удобным тебе способом.
Если переменная есть то считываешь её . тип переменной **TDateTime**

Answer (score 4):

Не получится. Ваша программа наверняка проинсталлирована на клиентской машине в каталог с правами на запись рута (администратора), то есть на Windows в `%PROGRAMFILES%`. А запущена она с правами клиента. То есть доступа к каталогу на запись нет, вы не сможете самоудалиться.

Конечно, вы можете просто прекратить работу программы (выдав соответствующее сообщение пользователю). Заметьте, однако, что ваша программа полностью под контролем пользователя, так что квалифицированный пользователь найдёт способ обойти ограничение.

PS: Вам обязательно `if`/`else`? А `case` никак-никак?